# Как убрать зазор между строками в консоли, чтобы выстроить вертикальную линию из ■?

Tags: c++, консоль, windows-10, вывод, символы

Мне нужно выстроить символы ■ в вертикальный ряд так, чтобы между ними не было зазоров или были, но минимальные. Подробнее о [символе ■](https://unicode-table.com/ru/25A0/).

В консоль вывожу так:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
cout << "■";
```

---

[image: символы]

Первый ряд - это то, что у меня есть. Второй ряд, это то, что мне нужно (создано в графическом редакторе). Но между ними остаётся зазор, тоже видно на картинке.

Пробовал менять шрифты - они могут максимум убрать вертикальный зазор между буквами, но не между ■.

Как можно убрать его? Или использовать другие символы вместо ■?

Comment: у меня в консоли хорошо работает символ 2588 - █. Но наверно это сильно зависит от консоли и настроек шрифта

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте подходящие символы.  В википедии есть целый список таких - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0. Мне подошел 2588 - █.